# How to compute rational points on a projective variety in Macaulay2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computational-algebra, macaulay2

I know that the package "rationalPoints" will compute rational points on an affine variety over a finite field, but I would like to do the same for varieties in projective space. Is there a built-in method?

Otherwise, I expect I could bootstrap one off of the affine case by dehomogenizing (lifting to the affine cone) then quotienting my point set by scalars.

Should I expect such a process to be notably faster than brute force for say, $\mathbb{P}^5_{\mathbb{F}_2}$? Can anyone give me some context for the algorithms implemented in "rationalPoints.m2"?